# Android Context with Alarm Managers

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-context

I am currently building a notes app. Each note can have an alarm to remind the user of that said note. I am wondering if I create the alarm within the program, but then rebuild it "on boot". Wont the context be different as the notes app wont be running at that time? If I am misunderstanding context could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

I just released my own Notes App with reminders, so here you go: When the device is rebooted, AlarmManager loses all your registered alarms. Because of this, you have to register your app to listen to the broadcast sent by the system when booting is finished, and then add all your reminders again.

Comment: Sorry this may be a stupid question, but if the app isnt running how can it listen for the broadcast?

Comment: By registering a Broadcast-Receiver with the Android system. Android invokes all registered receivers, in other words - you tell Android that you want to be informed about boot completed, and it will start your app (resp. the BroadcastReceiver class of it) when that event occurs.... Like the AlarmManager will start your app if the reminder you set is due, and your app is not running.